# Is it possible to obtain RGB values of a colormap?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colormap

I am new to colormaps in MATLAB, but I know their range of values go from 0 to 1 in a 64x3 matrix. If I go to the MATLAB documentation [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html), I'm referring to the color scales at the very bottom. Is it possible to get the range of RGB color values they seem to represent (in a 64x3 matrix) instead of values from 0 to 1? If not, is there a way to make a color palette similar to them?

Comment: For the matlab documentation I'm referring to the color scales at the very bottom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you want the current colormap, simply call `colormap` with no input arguments.

```
current = colormap();
```

If you want though, you can get the RGB values for any of the colormaps by using the functions that generate the colormaps directly along with an optional input which specifies the number of colors to use.

```
colors = gray();        % 64 grayscale values
colors = parula(100);   % 100 parula colors
colors = jet(10000);    % 10000 Jet colors
colors = hsv(10);       % 10 colors spanning the HSV colormap
```

Comment: I want to pick a specific colormap

Comment: @Mia See the update which allows you to get the RGB values for any of those color scale without having to first apply them to the figure.

Comment: I keep getting values from 0 to 1

Comment: @Mia In MATLAB they are `double` so they are between `0` and `1`. If you limit yourself to integers, then you can't create all of the gradiations that you need. You can multiply by `255` if you really need values between 0 and 255.

Comment: @Mia they are mapped to the `[0 1]` range to be able to use them as doubles. You are referring to `uint8` or `uint16` values. You can scale to those simply by mutliplying them with the appropriate number of elements (`2^n)`

Comment: Is it possible to convert them?

Comment: @Mia As I said above, multiply by 255 if you really want.

Comment: @Mia could you please ask a **single, contained question** and not ask dozens of folloow-up questions?

Comment: That being said it's *perfectly valid* for RGB values to be represented between 0 and 1. Also as I mentioned, if you don't force them to be integers you can more accurately represent all in-between colors.

Answer (score 2):

```
A=colormap('jet');
>> A
A =

         0         0    0.5625
         0         0    0.6250
         0         0    0.6875
         0         0    0.7500
         0         0    0.8125 % etc, size 64x3
```

These are the RGB values. It opens an empty figure because `colormap` internally calls `gcf`, thus opening a figure.